# How to Register Application Level Events with an Azure Service Bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I need to log the conversation in my chat bot. This is the code that I would put in the Global.asax if I had one but because I'm using the Bot Service I can't do it like that.

```
private void RegisterBotModules()
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("conversations_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(storageAccount, "conversations"));
    builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
}
```

How do I achieve the same with the bot service?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use bot builder instead of bot service?

Comment: I'm using a mac so it was the easiest to just create a bot in azure and start coding straight from the browser.